# Dynamic updating of prices with multiple options

Tags: javascript, html

```
script type="text/javascript">
   function updatePrice() {
      var price = document.getElementById("product").value;

      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="<p>PRICE: " + price + "</p>";
   }
</script>
</head>

<br>
<label >Shirt Type</label>

<body onload="updatePrice()">
<select id="product" onchange="updatePrice()">
<option id="basic" value="€20.00"> Basic Shirt (€20.00)</option>
<option id="poly" value="€25.00">Poly-Cotton Blend (€25.00)</option>
<option id="gildan" value="€28.00">Gildan Cotton (€28.00)</option>
<option id="organic" value="€30.00">Organic Cotton (€30.00)</option>
</select>
<div id="price"><p>PRICE: €XX.XX</p></div>

                <label >Shirt Size</label>

                <select id="size" onchange="updatePrice()">
                <option id="None">Choose Size</option>
                <option id="Small">Small</option>
                <option id="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option id ="Large">Large</option>
                <option id ="XL">XL</option>
                <option id ="XXL"value= "€2.00">XXL</option>
                <option id ="XXXL" value="€3.00">XXXL</option>

               </select>
```

I have a site which sells t-shirts, The code above allows the price to update depending on the type of cotton selected and that works fine. I want the XXL and XXXL size shirts to cost more and for that charge to be updated in the price. How do I add the values of elements together to display one price, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct code would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function updatePrice() {
  var price = document.getElementById("product").value;
  var size_price = document.getElementById("size").value;

  var a=parseInt(price);//parsed type price
  var b=parseInt(size_price);//parsed size price

  if(size_price != "null")//if the value selected is not null then add the prize
  {
        var fin_price = a+b; //add the prices
  }
  else //if the value selected is null then fin_prize=price 
  { 
       var fin_price = price;    
  }
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="<p>PRICE: " + fin_price + "</p>";
}
</script>

<br>
<label >Shirt Type</label>

<body onload="updatePrice()">
    <select id="product" onchange="updatePrice()">
         <option id="basic" value="20.00"> Basic Shirt (€20.00)</option>
         <option id="poly" value="25.00">Poly-Cotton Blend (€25.00)</option>
         <option id="gildan" value="28.00">Gildan Cotton (€28.00)</option>
         <option id="organic" value="30.00">Organic Cotton (€30.00)</option>
    </select>

    <div id="price"><p>PRICE: €XX.XX</p></div>

     <label >Shirt Size</label>

     <select id="size" onchange="updatePrice()">
         <option id="None" value="null">Choose Size</option>
         <option id="Small" value="0.00">Small</option>
         <option id="Medium" value="0.00">Medium</option>
         <option id ="Large" value="0.00">Large</option>
         <option id ="XL" value="0.00">XL</option>
         <option id ="XXL"value= "2.00">XXL</option>
         <option id ="XXXL" value="3.00">XXXL</option>
     </select>
```

**Note**:if you want to add numbers from different value attributes then numbers with letters (ie. €20.00) is discouraged.also use the value attribute with all options of a select dropdown

Comment: it's not quite working it displays the two numbers next to each other instead of adding one to the other

Comment: no the price doesn't change when the XXL or XXXL options are selected

Comment: @user3017497 this one finally works give it a try im sure of it

Answer (score 0):

Separate the formatting from the value.  Use float to preserve low order positions in case you ever want to use fractional prices.  Test with gildan and XXL.
(update with correction - price.toFixed(2))

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/threadid/dsu9rxe0/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updatePrice() {
    var discount = '.10';
    var discountFactor = 1.0-parseFloat(discount)
    var price = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("product").value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("size").value))*discountFactor;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML="<p>PRICE: €" + price.toFixed(2) + "</p>";
  }

</script>
</head>

<br>
<label >Shirt Type</label>

<body onload="updatePrice()">
<select id="product" onchange="updatePrice()">
<option id="basic" value="20.00"> Basic Shirt (€20.00)</option>
<option id="poly" value="25.00">Poly-Cotton Blend (€25.00)</option>
<option id="gildan" value="28.30">Gildan Cotton (€28.30)</option>
<option id="organic" value="30.00">Organic Cotton (€30.00)</option>
</select>
<div id="price"><p>PRICE: €XX.XX</p></div>

                <label >Shirt Size</label>

                <select id="size" onchange="updatePrice()">
                <option id="None" value= "0.00">Choose Size</option>
                <option id="Small" value= "0.00">Small</option>
                <option id="Medium" value= "0.00">Medium</option>
                <option id ="Large" value= "0.00">Large</option>
                <option id ="XL" value= "0.00">XL</option>
                <option id ="XXL" value= "2.25">XXL</option>
                <option id ="XXXL" value="3.00">XXXL</option>

               </select>
```

Comment: do I have to change the div that displays price? it's coming out with the x's

Comment: Apologies.  Rushing - bad form.  Udated with correction - price.toString(2).  I do recommend using float to preserve low order positions in case you ever want to use fractional prices. Test with gildan and XXL.

Comment: As an extension of this how would I go about applying a discount to the price if the user had a certain email address, say a 10% discount. Thanks

Comment: @user3017497  You need to figure out how to provide the discount:     var discount = '.10';
   var discountFactor = 1.0-parseFloat(discount)
      var price = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("product").value) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("size").value))*discountFactor;

Comment: Doesnt work comes out as a crazy float number, the discount is conditional it only applies if you have a certain email address